# I cannot find the Georeferencer GDAL on QGIS 3,14 Pi

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-plugins, georeferencing

I only have 7 plugins installed and Georeferencer GDAL is not one of them any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

The georeference Plugin is a core plugin and can't be deinstalled (just de-activated). You find the plugin (after activation) in the menu raster:

[image]